# Need something other than touchup inside

Tags: iphone

I have a button in my iphone app, when I click the button it calls a linked method, that I have done as:

```
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

all working well, but i want if user tap the button for say 5 second continuously then he will be shown a  message that will be there and gone away after some time and button does not get clicked, how can I do that, please help me.

Many Thanks in advance.
Regards
iPhone Developer11

Answer (score 1):

Youcould use `UIControlEventTouchDown` and make sure it is touched down in the right view and if it is start a timer. If there are no UIControlEventTouchUpInside for 5 seconds you do whatever you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

You should check docs for UILongPressGestureRecognizer. I think it fits your requirements.

Comment: +1 This is definitely a job for a gesture recognizer. I recently wrote an interface with a grid of images that if you tap them, navigate to details about that image, but if you press and hold, pop up an alert to confirm, and then deletes that image.